# Look Up Field no Search Results when inline edit

Tags: search, inlineeditsupport, inline, search-layout, lookup-field

in my sandbox i have a custom object(vessel__c) with custom fields (Project_codeword__c,vessel_name__c).
[image]
case is using a lookup field on this object.
When I create a new case and start typing, suggestions appear with the first two fields from my search layout. Here I can search for both the Project Codeword and the Vessel Name and get the correct records displayed.

But when I do inline edit in an existing record, I get no results for the vesselname only for the codeword. Is this a bug or is there a setting somewhere else for this behavior?
Here is a screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. Please click 'affects me' so that it can be fixed quickly
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BFXQA2&title=inline-edit-of-a-filtered-lookup-does-not-work-in-lightning